# How to change the behavior of a package via the class options?

Tags: document-classes, class-options

I'm writing a document class based on the `book` class. In this class I have some code as below:

```
\RequirePackage[total={10cm,18cm},paperwidth=16cm, paperheight=23cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[cross,center,noinfo,a4]{crop}
```

I want to define an option for my class, say, `nocrop` so that when I use it, the above code change into the code below:

```
\RequirePackage[total={10cm,18cm}]{geometry}
%\RequirePackage[cross,center,noinfo,a4]{crop}
```

In other words, I want the `crop` package to be exempted from being run and the `paperwidth=16cm, paperheight=23cm` to be deleted.

**Is this possible? if yes, how?**
Here is my MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
% my class file
\begin{filecontents}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{book}
\RequirePackage[total={10cm,18cm},paperwidth=16cm, paperheight=23cm]{geometry}
 \RequirePackage[cross,center,noinfo,a4]{crop}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{myclass} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

(I'm using XeLaTeX on a Windows machine, if it helps.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A switch (`\ifmyclass@crop`) can be defined, that is set via the option and asked later to include the right set of packages/options:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
% my class file
\begin{filecontents}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\newif\ifmyclass@crop
\myclass@croptrue % default
\DeclareOption{nocrop}{\myclass@cropfalse}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{book}
\ifmyclass@crop
  \RequirePackage[total={10cm,18cm},paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=23cm]{geometry}
  \RequirePackage[cross,center,noinfo,a4]{crop}
\else
  \RequirePackage[total={10cm,18cm}]{geometry}
\fi
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I use `‎‎\documentclass[nocrop]‎{myclass}`, I get two errors: `! File ended while scanning use of ^^M.` and `! Emergency stop.`.

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan: Two minutes after the first post, I have added a missing `]` in `RequirePackage[total={10cm,18cm}]{geometry}`. Perhaps your browser has showed you the old version.